# How to update multiple rows at once in MySQL with calculated date

Tags: php, mysql

How to update multiple rows at once in MySQL wit calculated data from db.

```
oid    value1     value2     sum
1       10         20
2        5         -2
3        3          0
4        1         90
```

I should  update the "sum" with php7 at once

Is there a simple option?

Comment: what is expected outcome??? As well as tell us condition based on which table will going to be updated.Most important add your attempt what you have tried so far?

Comment: table sum will be updated :   value1 - value2 = sum

Comment: 5 - -2 = 7 is that the outcome you expect or is there a rule about this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

A simple update: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

```
UPDATE your-table SET sum = value1 - value2
```